# VB Code for MS Project

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-project

I am trying to get the below code (MS Project Text Color Change) to work, but when I put it in a module in MPP it gives me an error. It is probably me, not the code.

This code is supposed to look at status and change the text color accordingly. I cut and paste this code into a module, but I get an error when I run it that says compile error.

Then it highlights the second line below.

```
Sub CompletePercentSub()

Dim t As Task Dim i As Integer

'Iterates through the entire ms project file

i = 1 For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks

SelectRow Row:=i, RowRelative:=False

If Not t Is Nothing Then

    Select Case t.Status
        Case 0 'Complete
            Font32Ex CellColor:=&H98FB98 'LIGHT GREEN
        Case 1 'On Schedule
            Font32Ex CellColor:=&HE0FFFF 'TAN
        Case 2 'Late
            Font32Ex CellColor:=&HC0FF& 'LIGHT RED
        Case 2 'Future Task
            Font32Ex CellColor:=&HFFFFFF 'WHITE
    End Select
End If
i = i + 1

Next t

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the corrected version of the macro above:

```
Sub CompletePercentSub()

Dim t As Task
Dim i As Integer

i = 1
For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
    SelectRow Row:=i, RowRelative:=False
    If Not t Is Nothing Then
        Select Case t.Status
            Case 0 'Complete
                Font32Ex CellColor:=&H98FB98 'LIGHT GREEN
            Case 1 'On Schedule
                Font32Ex CellColor:=&HE0FFFF 'TAN
            Case 2 'Late
                Font32Ex CellColor:=&HC0FF& 'LIGHT RED
            Case 3 'Future Task
                Font32Ex CellColor:=&HFFFFFF 'WHITE
        End Select
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next t

End Sub
```

[image: sample formatted schedule, version 1]

And here is an alternative version based on your previous-now-deleted-question. Adjust as necessary.

```
Sub FormatTasksByStatus()

    FilterClear
    OutlineShowAllTasks
    
    SelectAll
    Font32Ex Color:=RGB(255, 255, 255), CellColor:=RGB(0, 0, 0)
    
    Dim NumTasks As Long
    NumTasks = ActiveProject.Tasks.Count
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To NumTasks
        SelectRow Row:=i, RowRelative:=False
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim tsk As Task
        Set tsk = ActiveCell.Task
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Dim cc As Long
            cc = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Dim fc As Long
            fc = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            
            If tsk.PercentComplete = 100 Then
                fc = RGB(128, 128, 128)         ' complete = grey
            
            ElseIf tsk.PercentComplete = 0 Then
                If Fix(tsk.Start) < Date Then
                    fc = RGB(255, 0, 0)         ' late start = red
                ElseIf Fix(tsk.Start) < (Date + 5) Then
                    cc = RGB(255, 255, 0)       ' starting soon = yellow
                End If
                
            ElseIf tsk.PercentComplete < 100 Then
                If Fix(tsk.Finish) < Date Then
                    fc = RGB(255, 0, 0)         ' late finish = red
                ElseIf Fix(tsk.Finish) < (Date + 3) Then
                    cc = RGB(255, 255, 0)       ' finishing soon = yellow
                Else
                    fc = RGB(0, 0, 255)         ' finishing later = blue
                    If IsDate(tsk.BaselineStart) Then
                        If tsk.Start < tsk.BaselineStart Then
                            cc = RGB(0, 255, 0) ' green = started early
                        End If
                    End If
                   
                End If
                
            End If
            Font32Ex Color:=fc, CellColor:=cc
        End If
        Err.Clear
    Next i

End Sub
```

[image: sample formatted schedule, version 2]